# Finite Subgroups Of $GL(2,\mathbb{R})$

Tags: group-theory

I have the following question:

Is it true that every finite subgroup of odd order in $GL(2,\mathbb{R})$ is cyclic?

Thanks!

Comment: To help you: first look at finite subgroups of $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$...

Comment: Yes, it is true. It is probably easiest to consider such a group as a subgroup of ${\rm GL}(2,\mathbb{C})$ and then think about its character..

Comment: Well, the subgroup *is* in $SL(2,\mathbb R)$ as its elements have determinants which are real roots of unity of odd order and the only subgroups of $SL(2,\mathbb C)$ which are of odd-order are cyclic.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of providing an answer. Extend the ground field to $\mathbb{C}.$ Then the representation of the group is completely reducible. Since the group has odd order, it has no complex irreducible character of degree $2.$ Hence the group is reducible, and must be conjugate to a group of diagonal matrices. Thus it is Abelian. Furthermore, since the character afforded by the representation is real, it must have the form $\lambda + \overline{\lambda}$ for some degree $1$ character $\lambda.$ Then $\lambda$ must already be faithful, since $\lambda$ and $\overline{\lambda}$ have the same kernel.
Thus the group is cyclic.